# BAPI_PRDSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI2 - Net weight becomes Zero

Tags: abap, bapi, function-module, sap-apo

APO Experts,
Where in the BAPI_PRDSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI2 are internal tables appending the updated values to the database? I am having trouble because when I passed 34.5 for net weight in this bapi BAPI_PRDSRVAPS_SAVEMULTI2, after COMMIT, value in MARM becomes 0. Is there other processing that might be the cause of that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, we should not only populate the alternative UOM internal table, should also fill the header internal table for product_int and base_uom fields.

Hope this helps.